# run linux command succeed but failed in .sh file. "No such file or directory "

Tags: linux

I wrote a linux command and it runs perfectly in command line:

```
/bin/netstat -an | grep '3306' | sed 's/.*/[MYSQLMON]&/' > /home/bbWifiExt/logs/WIFIMonitor.log
```

however when I copy this code to .sh and run the .sh file i got:

No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me why? Many thanks.

Comment: How did you run the .sh file?

Comment: Thanks. I entered the full path of the sh file:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must either call it as

```
sh mycommand.sh
```

or make your shell script executable. Insert `#! /bin/sh` or `#! /bin/bash` as the first line and

```
chmod +x mycommand.sh
```

before calling

```
mycommand.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I found the problem, because the extra space in the sh file. Thanks:D

Comment: @user986275 So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 1):

for my situation (rename and copied file from windows to linux) the solution was :

> dos2unix script.sh

Answer (score 0):

If the first line of the script something like

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and the execute bit set i.e.

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Heal. I found the problem, because the extra space in the sh file. Thanks:D